# Xdebug 3 "Cannot evaluate code without a connection" when using readline()

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I am using Visual Studio Code and have installed Xdebug 3.

I am trying to run the following code:

```php
<?php

print("Please enter something:");
$something = readline();
print($something);

?>
```

However, when I run the code and enter some text, I get the error message

> Cannot evaluate code without a connection

[image: as shown in this image]

How am I able to make it so that `readline` works and is able to provide a value to the `$something` variable?

**php.ini**

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_upon_error = yes
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.log = C:/xampp/php/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms = 2000
```

**EDIT:**

**[xdebug_info() pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AvaaDypd)**

Comment: I don't see a breakpoint being set? I also am not sure whether the "Debug Console" is the same thing as a normal Terminal console...

Comment: I have tried setting a breakpoint at each line to see if that would let me enter text, but it did not work.